# Can i combine DXF, Google Earth Models, Shape Files and Rasters in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, google-earth, autocad, dxf

I'm an architect, trying to bring a number of data sets together for use in a CAD package (AutoCAD).  I have some georeferenced images (.jpg, .jgw.), Some model files downloaded from GoogleEarth (.kml and .skp), as well as digimap data such as vector maps (.shp) and contour profiles (.dxf). AutoCAD does not support georeferencing, so i'd like to combine this information in another package, such as QGIS, and then export it for working on within AutoCAD.

I've been playing with this, and not had much look.  I can't see how to import model files (.skp) or lines (.dxf), and i'm not sure if this is possible.  Also, export is failing for the DXF export of vector lines from things like the OS local map.

Any ideas about these problems, or other suggestions as to programmes that could bring these various kinds of information together?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "Also, export is failing for the DXF export of vector lines from things like the OS local map"?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS supports [DXF](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html) through OGR. It's a bit of a minefield, though, as the format isn't clearly defined.

Can you export your model in any other format than SketchUp SKP? QGIS is a traditional “2½D” GIS system, so 3D models would be represented as 2D with elevation as an attribute at each node.